# Ubuntu psql: could not connect to server

Tags: ubuntu, psql

I have a local installation of postgresql. It does not start, as I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Starting it manually does not work:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
  * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server
  * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
       2015-03-09 17:41:39 CET [3769-1] FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
```

Ok, something wrong with the permissions. Lets look at them:

```
ls -all /var/run/
drwxr-xr-x 27 root        root         900 Mar  9 17:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root        root        4096 Feb 28 06:19 ..
drwxrwsr-x  3 postgres-xc postgres-xc   60 Mar  9 17:35 postgresql
```

I found the following: doing `sudo chmod 777 /var/run/postgresql` solves the problem and a can start postgresql afterwards. Unfortunatly this has to be done after every reboot of Ubuntu. SO two questions:
1.Whats wrong? Why is the chmod not permanently?
2. How to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I found a solution. A remove, purge and reinstall of postgresql did not solve the problem. I think some artefacts of earlier versions still remained (as I, for instance, still found 9.1,9.3 and 9.4 as subdirectories in /etc/postgresql/). Here is the full set of commands that I did to set up a clean installation:

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
sudo apt-get purge postgresql
apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql/
sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
sudo rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
sudo rm -r /var/run/postgres
userdel -r postgres
sudo userdel -r postgres
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

after this, the problem was no longer present.

Comment: found solution ? @SoyuzbekOrozbekUulu

Comment: @Jorgelig Just completely removed postgresql server from pc. Obviously solution doesn't exist.

Comment: this worked for me in that I can now long into psql. However, all my databases are gone. Any idea how to add them back ? The data is still all in a local volume