# pg_lsclusters shows owner root

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-10

I tried to enter PostgreSQL terminal with `psql` but I got following:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket 
"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

when I tried to `pg_lsclusters` I got this:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 down   root  /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

So, how I can to change Owner to postgres rather than root?

Comment: That is Debian/Ubuntu, right? What do you get if you try starting the server with `pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main` as user `postgres`?

Comment: I found an answer from this [address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947498/ubuntu-psql-could-not-connect-to-server)

Comment: Anyone falling into the same problem follow this thread. [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/can-not-connect-to-postgresql-listening-on-port-5432)